# fastest way to "parse" specific string

Tags: c++, parsing

I need to parse string like `"<double>,<double>,<char[12]>"`, e.g. something like `"12.34555,23.44343343,abcdef"`.

However I want to make it as fast as possible.

---

As we know `<charconv>` does not really work for `double`, so only options I can see are `strtod` or `sscanf`.

Did not tested `<iostreams>` it seems always to be very slow, also include memory allocations.

Another nice option is to create own `strtod` function - I tried but is very difficult to make it right (same problem as in `<charconv>`)

`sscanf` implementation seems very clean, but I am not sure how fast it will be.

Bonus will be if the code works on non NULL terminated strings, e.g. `std::string_view`.

Just for illustration, here is `sscanf` code:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstring>

void scan(const char *s){
    double a = 0;
    double b = 0;
    char h[32];
    // fill, in order to see if it was parsed
    memset(h, 'x', 31); h[31] = '\0';

    sscanf(s, "%lf,%lf,%s", &a, &b, h);

    printf("%.4lf\t%.4lf\t%s\n", a, b, h);
}

int main() {
    scan("12.34555,23.44343343,abcdef");
    scan("12.34555,,abcdef");
    scan("12.34555,23.44343343,");
    scan("12.34555,23.44343343");
    scan("12.34555,");
    scan("12.34555");
    scan("");
    scan("boba");
}
```

---

In order to speed up I can make it fixed decimal digits too if this will help, e.g.

`"+12.12345678,-12.12345678,abcde1234512"`.

However the code needs to be able to check it if wrong string is passed.

Comment: If you decide to use the type-unsafe `sscanf` function, remember to add a limit to the string you attempt to read. Otherwise you'll sooner or later end up with a buffer overflow.

Comment: And why not simply build a program which tries all of the different possibilities, build it with optimization enabled, and then just try it out with timing of the functions? And remember to try each function a few thousand times to get a decent average.

Comment: Or just try the simple naive way first, and ***if*** you have any kind of requirement for timings, *then* you look if this is the top bottleneck, and only if it is then try to fix it.

Comment: Is there a practical purpose for this or is it just mental masturbation? Libraries like [zsv](https://github.com/liquidaty/zsv) parse CSVs using SIMD operations.

Comment: `const char *s` as argument (i.o std::string_view), direct use of printf and memset... are you sure you are writing C++?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude yes there is a limit. two floats, and one string 12 characters. Can someone pass larger - yes. but we know the input size

Comment: @PepijnKramer yes, is C++17. but example is for sscanf, so is like C.

Comment: I would certainly consider third party libraries such as Google's [double conversion](https://github.com/google/double-conversion). But the only way to be sure is to time different approaches.

Comment: @Botje seems they use `strtod`, this has to be the way to go.

Comment: So instead of e.g. `sscanf("...,%s", ...)` use `sscanf("..., %12s", ...)`. Otherwise, if you get something larger your current code using `sscanf` risk buffer overflow.

Comment: As for checking for garbage after the string, you could use the `%n` format to get the number of characters scanned so far, and use it to check for the string terminator in the source string.

Comment: And if you go the `sscanf` route, remember to *always* check what it [returns](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fscanf#Return_value)!